# How to apply jQuery validation engine with chosen.js?

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen, jquery-validation-engine

I tried running the code from the author to make chosen.js work with jquery validation engine

**[Here](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/blob/master/demos/demoChosenLibrary.html)** is the authors code

I used the same code to test, but it is not working

This is my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
                jQuery("#formID").validationEngine({
                    prettySelect : true,
                    useSuffix: "_chzn"
                    //promptPosition : "bottomLeft"
        });
        $("#country").chosen({
                    allow_single_deselect : true
        });
});
```

**[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/a27d3pq7/7/)** is my fiddle

I don't know whats wrong in my code?

Comment: Did you try this locally and got the same error? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952320/shell-form-does-not-validate-jsfiddle/18952586

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question

I solved the problem by changing **"_chzn"** to **"_chosen"**. Also added **validateNonVisibleFields = true** as `chosen select` hides the `actual select`

```
jQuery('#formID').validationEngine({
           validateNonVisibleFields: true, 
           prettySelect : true,
           useSuffix: "_chosen"
  });
```

Comment: Your code worked for me by removing prettySelect option. It raises javascript error field.position is undefined at line 1863 - Validation Engine 2.6.2.

Comment: You need to provide `promptposition` either during initialization or in `<select>` tag as `data-prompt-position`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15336860/4331291) answer